# Convex relaxation of rank constraint

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-rank, semidefinite-programming, nuclear-norm, relaxations

I would like to approximate a symmetric matrix $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ by a matrix of rank no more than $r$, i.e., a matrix $Z=EE'$ where $E\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$, for some given $r\leq n$.

Naturally, the following optimization problem arises:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf{P}_0:\ \text{Min.}\ \|EE'-X\|_{F}
\end{aligned}
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf{P}_1:\ &\text{Min.}\ \|Z-X\|_{F}\\
&\mathrm{rank}(Z)  \leq r.
\end{aligned}
$$

Here $\|\cdot\|_F$ stands for the Frobenius norm.

I would like to approximate this problem with a convex relaxation. I believe that one possible approach would be to move the rank constraint into the cost function using the nuclear norm trying this way to force the rank of $X$ to be low:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf{P}_2:\ &\text{Min.}\ \|Z-X\|_{F} + \mu \|Z\|_*.
\end{aligned}
$$

We would then try to solve with different values of $\mu>0$ until we obtain a solution which has rank no larger than $r$.

Another possible approach would be to formulate the following problem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf{P}_3:\ &\text{Min.}\ \|Z-X\|_{F}\\
&\|Z\|_* \leq \alpha,
\end{aligned}
$$

and choose $\alpha>0$ somehow so as to force the rank of $Z$ to be lower than $r$.

I was not able, however, to find an inequality that links the nuclear norm to the rank of a matrix and I am not sure there exists one - correct if I am wrong.

My questions are:

1. Do $\mathsf{P}_2$ and $\mathsf{P}_2$ make sense?
2. What are some other ways to approximately solve $\mathsf{P}_1$?

Comment: $P_0$ and $P_1$ are not equivalent unless $X$ is symmetric.

Comment: That is true. I added the assumption that $X$ is symmetric.

Comment: The norm and rank are unrelated as such.

Comment: How big is $n$? The following suggests that my previous comment is misleading: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-significance-of-the-nuclear-norm

Comment: Why not truncate the SVD of $\rm X$?

Comment: @copper.hat can be up to a few hundreds.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo assuming there are no other constraints on $X$, that is precisely how it should be done. But perhaps this is but the objective of a larger model.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Truncating the SVD could be a solution, but I would prefer an approach which can be generalized when, say, $\mathsf{P}_0$ has additional constraints (e.g., of the form $\mathcal{A}(X) = b$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a linear operator).